# Javascript not responding on razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to do a cascading on my dropdown list.
my C# code

```
  public JsonResult OnPostEmployeeSelect(string Id)
    {
        ViewData["Department"] = new SelectList(_context.Department.OrderBy(o => o.Name), "Id", "Name");
        Guid DepartmentId = new Guid(Id);
        List<Employees> Employees = new List<Employees>();          
        return new JsonResult(Employees.Where(w => w.DepartmentId == DepartmentId).OrderBy(o => o.FullName));
    }
```

my javascript:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DepartmentDropdown").change(function () {

            var Id = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Create?handler=EmployeeSelect",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Id
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#Employeedropdown").empty();
                    $("#Employeedropdown").append(response);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

I dont know whats the problem after selecting department nothing happens EmployeeDropdown remains null.
How can I fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

The action is searching parameter with the name 'Id'.
The data in the ajax should be: 
data: {Id: Id}
Also `$("#Employeedropdown").append(response)` will not work.
`$("#Employeedropdown")`, what kind of element is it? you should append tag elements not a json data.

Comment: Also remove `contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'` - this is unnecessary when passing single string value.

Comment: $("#Employeedropdown") its an Id for the second dropdown